# paypal no shipping address on file

Tags: 7, commerce, payment-gateways

**Problem statement:** When users pay for an order at paypal, in almost 50% cases(for both verified and unverified paypal users) the transaction slip(for business account) does show shipping address(confirmed address), but for other 50% users it is saying **"We have no shipping address on file"** even if users enter shipping details on paypal review page.

Using Paypal Express Checkout payment Method.

Currently we are passing NOSHIPPING=1

What should be the parameter for NOSHIPPING ? What could be the problem ?
Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try not passing that parameter at all

Here is an excerpt from the [PayPal's Express Checkout Integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECCustomizing/#suppressing-the-buyers-shipping-address)  about Shipping address:

> **Suppressing the Buyer's Shipping Address**
>
> You can suppress the display of the buyer's shipping address on the
> PayPal pages. You might want to do this in these cases:
>
> 1. You are selling a product or service that does not require shipping.
> 2. You prefer to handle addresses completely on your own and do not want
>    to let buyers choose from their PayPal address book.
>
> `To suppress` the display of the buyer's shipping address, `set the NOSHIPPING parameter to 1`
> in the call to SetExpressCheckout. No shipping address displays
> on Express Checkout pages.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tested this as of today and it works: I removed both `NOSHIPPING` and the `REQCONFIRMSHIPPING` fields from the `SetExpressCheckout` call.